# How do I track and view total stand time using the Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

The Apple Watch can monitor if you stand at least 1 minute during 12 different hours in the day. If you do, that is counted as 12 stand hours. But you could have actually stood for 12 minutes or 12 hours during that day.

Is there a way to see the actual amount of time that you stood or sat in that hour?  Or the total amount of time that you stood or sat during the day?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated the apple watch counts the stand goal as 1 minute of standing every hour for 12 hours.

from Apple

> "The Stand ring shows hours in which you've stood and moved for at least a minute. Complete your daily Stand goal by standing up and moving around for at least 1 minute during 12 different hours in the day. Even if you stand all day, you still need to move around."

As far as I am aware there is no other metrics that are viewable to the user.